# Choice of mosfet transistor for linear operation (voltage controlled dummy load / current source)

Tags: mosfet, component-selection, documentation

**BACKGROUND**

I have built very simple dummy load to test thermal behavior of some switching power supply (5V 5A). Vbat is 8-9V from 6F22 battery. Resistors are oversized to reduce working temperature.

[image]

Photo:

[image]

It works well for the purpose for which it was built, but I probably should add some capacitor at op-amp noninverting input.

Now I want to build better version of this and use 0R1 shunt with low temperature coefficient, add voltage control and **use diffrent transistor**. BUZ11A is obsolete and I want to use something with bigger package (like TO-247) and use CPU radiator with fan.

In current version I have choosen BUZ11A from few mosfet types I had in my workshop because this transfer characteristic was clear for me and I can assume that this transistor needs Vgs from ~4V to ~5V to get from 0A to way more than 5A (which is my requirement).

[image]

But many high power transistors have "incomplete" transfer characteristic documented like this:

[image]

[image]

**Question 1:**

Why this is documented like this? I should not use this transistor in this area (low Vgs)? It is not stable at this region?

**Question2:**

Can I use big transistor (like BUZ11A) to regulate small currents? Let's say I want to use big mosfet transistor to build voltage controlled current source regulated from 0.5mA to 5A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Why this is documented like this? I should not use this transistor in
> this area (low Vgs)? It is not stable at this region?*

Yes, it's not thermally stable in this region. For instance, in the IRFP260, if you applied 4 volts gate-source voltage at 25°C the initial typical current will be 1 amp but, if the voltage across the MOSFET was more than a volt or so, the power dissipation would cause the MOSFET to warm. As it warms it draws more current and that causes a massive uplift in warming and, about a millisecond later the junction is at 175°C and the MOSFET is taking 10 amps and dissipating one hundred times the power. It doesn't end well either.

[image]

That is what that graph is telling you. Of course you have your MOSFET in a closed-loop control but, if that closed-loop control isn't fast enough to cope with the sudden ramp up of current (and, it really can take less than 1 ms for this to happen), then the MOSFET will be wasted and, it might not even feel warm to the touch. And, you'll be left pondering what happened.

> *It works well for the purpose for which it was built, but I probably
> should add some capacitor at op-amp noninverting input.*

**General note** - when using MOSFETs as a controlled current source you need to run a tight ship in the control loop or they will die on you. Adding capacitors may stabilize your loop electronically but they may add so much time-lag that the MOSFET dies due to thermal runaway (as described above).

> *Can I use big transistor (like BUZ11A) to regulate small currents?*

Sure you can but you have to watch what the leakage is of the [BUZ11A](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/buz11-d.pdf) because it is specified at up to 1 mA of leakage. Read the data sheet and look for \$I_{DSS}\$.

Comment: Thanks. Can you expand "you need to run a tight ship in the control loop" part a little? Do you mean low delay / low impedance control loop?

Comment: Yes, he does -- given that you've chosen to drive your power resistors in common-source, you're going a long way toward tightening that ship, though.  The resistors in that position will give an immediate negative feedback as the current goes up; that'll give the op-amp time to catch up.

Comment: The control loop needs to be quick. Yes, a low delay; probably a loop bandwidth of greater than 10 kHz i.e. no sloppy slow response or the MOSFET could easily die. It's called [The Spirito Effect](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/files/NESC-TB-10-01_Power_MOSFET_Thermal_Instability-1-28-10_NRB_TECH_BULLETIN_FINAL.pdf) and has caught many folk out on high power current limiters.

Comment: Given the type of circuit you have, there can be "electronic" instability due to the delay incurred by the MOSFET and this is due to gate capacitance AND, it may be necessary to use a BJT buffer to drive that gate capacitance - fitted between op-amp output and MOSFET gate as an emitter follower but, it's a trade-off because the BJT incurs a small delay too!!

Comment: @Andyaka Wait a moment, I meant adding capacitor in parallel to my potentiometer. Not at the inverting input. Adding capacitor to noninverting input can cause time-lag too?

Comment: That's OK; the input demand signal is outside the feedback loop. However, due to gate-source capacitance and a dwindling value of the source resistor (0R9 in your schematic) - you say you want to use 0R1 - the circuit may go electronically unstable. This often happens and, the fix is to slow down the op-amp control circuit by adding capacitors (which you might need to do) and that's where you lose the ability to quickly respond to thermal runaway problems with the MOSFET.